# Is it possible to identify a Facebook or LinkedIn user based on phone number?

Tags: facebook, api, linkedin-api

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to differentiate between Facebook/LinkedIn users with identical names based on their phone number and/or address. I am not interested in getting their information from Facebook or LinkedIn(AFAIK this is not possible), just picking the correct profile based on their contact information.

Has anyone achieved this?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you cannot retrieve a user's Facebook profile info using their phone number.

Answer (score 1):

Likewise for LinkedIn. There is no phone number lookup.